# Solving adventcode day 6 puzzle: toggling lights in a grid

Tags: programming-challenge, f#

I have solved the [day 6 adventcode problem](http://adventofcode.com/day/6):

> --- Day 6: Probably a Fire Hazard ---
>
> Because your neighbors keep defeating you in the holiday house
>   decorating contest year after year, you've decided to deploy one
>   million lights in a 1000x1000 grid.
>
> Furthermore, because you've been especially nice this year, Santa has
>   mailed you instructions on how to display the ideal lighting
>   configuration.
>
> Lights in your grid are numbered from 0 to 999 in each direction; the
>   lights at each corner are at 0,0, 0,999, 999,999, and 999,0. The
>   instructions include whether to turn on, turn off, or toggle various
>   inclusive ranges given as coordinate pairs. Each coordinate pair
>   represents opposite corners of a rectangle, inclusive; a coordinate
>   pair like 0,0 through 2,2 therefore refers to 9 lights in a 3x3
>   square. The lights all start turned off.
>
> To defeat your neighbors this year, all you have to do is set up your
>   lights by doing the instructions Santa sent you in order.
>
> For example:
>
> turn on 0,0 through 999,999 would turn on (or leave on) every light.
>   toggle 0,0 through 999,0 would toggle the first line of 1000 lights,
>   turning off the ones that were on, and turning on the ones that were
>   off. turn off 499,499 through 500,500 would turn off (or leave off)
>   the middle four lights. After following the instructions, how many
>   lights are lit?
>
> --- Part Two ---
>
> You just finish implementing your winning light pattern when you
>   realize you mistranslated Santa's message from Ancient Nordic Elvish.
>
> The light grid you bought actually has individual brightness controls;
>   each light can have a brightness of zero or more. The lights all start
>   at zero.
>
> The phrase turn on actually means that you should increase the
>   brightness of those lights by 1.
>
> The phrase turn off actually means that you should decrease the
>   brightness of those lights by 1, to a minimum of zero.
>
> The phrase toggle actually means that you should increase the
>   brightness of those lights by 2.
>
> What is the total brightness of all lights combined after following
>   Santa's instructions?
>
> For example:
>
> turn on 0,0 through 0,0 would increase the total brightness by 1.
>   toggle 0,0 through 999,999 would increase the total brightness by
>   2000000.

Here is my F# code. I would like feedback how to improve this.

https://github.com/naveensrinivasan/adventcode/blob/master/6.fsx

```
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let filereadlines f = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__, f ))

type Switch = On | Off | Brightness of int

type Action = On | Off | Toggle

type MessageLanguage = Nordic | English

type Instruction = {
  Operation : Action ;
  StartRow  : int;
  StartCol : int;
  EndRow : int;
  EndCol : int;
  Language  : MessageLanguage
}

let toggle = function
            | Switch.On -> Switch.Off 
            |_  ->  Switch.On 

let getInstruction (line:string) (lang:MessageLanguage)= 
                  let matches = Regex.Matches(line, "[\w\d_]+")
                                        |> Seq.cast<Match>
                                        |> Seq.filter (fun f -> f.Success) |> Seq.map(fun f-> f.Value) 

                  let action = if matches |> Seq.nth 0 = "toggle" then Toggle
                                  elif matches |> Seq.nth 1 = "on"   then  On
                                  else Off 

                  let elementat n= matches |> Seq.nth n |> int

                  match action with
                  |Toggle -> {Operation = action; StartRow = elementat 1; StartCol = elementat 2; 
                                EndRow = elementat 4 ; EndCol = elementat 5; Language = lang}
                  |_ -> {Operation = action; StartRow = elementat 2; StartCol = elementat 3;
                          EndRow = elementat 5 ; EndCol = elementat 6; Language= lang} 

let translateCode (state:Switch) (lang :MessageLanguage) (action:Action) =
    match lang,action,state with
    |English, Toggle,_ ->  toggle state 
    |English, On,_ ->   Switch.On 
    |Nordic, Toggle,Brightness(x)  ->  Brightness (x+2) 
    |Nordic, On,Brightness(x) ->  Brightness (x+1) 
    |Nordic, Off ,Brightness(x) when x = 0 ->  Brightness (0) 
    |Nordic, Off ,Brightness(x)  ->  Brightness (x-1) 
    |_,_,_ ->  Switch.Off 

let lights =Array2D.create 1000 1000 Switch.Off

"6.txt"
|> filereadlines
|> Seq.map (fun f -> getInstruction f English)
|> Seq.iter(fun ins -> 
        for i in  ins.StartRow .. ins.EndRow do
            for j in ins.StartCol .. ins.EndCol  do
                lights.[i, j] <- translateCode lights.[i, j] ins.Language ins.Operation)

lights 
|> Seq.cast<Switch> 
|> Seq.filter(fun f -> f = Switch.On)
|> Seq.length
|> printfn "The number of lights that are turned on are %i"


let nordiclights =Array2D.create 1000 1000 (Brightness 0)
"6.txt"
|> filereadlines
|> Seq.map (fun f -> getInstruction f Nordic)
|> Seq.iter(fun ins -> 
        for i in  ins.StartRow .. ins.EndRow do
            for j in ins.StartCol .. ins.EndCol  do
                nordiclights.[i, j] <- translateCode nordiclights.[i, j] ins.Language ins.Operation)

nordiclights 
|> Seq.cast<Switch> 
|> Seq.map(fun f -> match f with
                       |Brightness(x) -> x
                       |_ -> 0)
|> Seq.sum 
|> printfn "The Santa's real nordic decoded message and the total brightness is %i"
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your fist question

Answer (score 3):

First off: good job on the code!  It's nice and clear, and easy to
follow what it does and what it should do.

## Style

### Spaces

First off, a small remark about the spacing.  I think it's interesting
to write pattern matching without a space after the first character
(`|`), because it looks like some ascii tree if you end the list with
the "default" matcher (`|_`).  But I would not recommend it,
especially while the spacing is not really consistent in the file.

I saw you already reformatted the code on github, which is a good
thing!  Consistent spacing makes it easier for other programmers to
read the code and not get distracted.

### Alignment of pattern matching

Although this partly depends on what kind of editor you are using,
you could make some pattern matchings more clear by aligning them.
For instance:

```
let toggle = function
            | Switch.On -> Switch.Off
            | _ -> Switch.On
```

could become

```
let toggle = function
            | Switch.On -> Switch.Off
            | _         -> Switch.On
```

And

```
let translateCode (state: Switch) (lang: MessageLanguage) (action: Action) =
    match lang, action, state with
        | English, Toggle, _ -> toggle state
        | English, On, _ -> Switch.On
        | Nordic, Toggle, Brightness(x) -> Brightness (x+2)
        | Nordic, On, Brightness(x) -> Brightness (x+1)
        | Nordic, Off, Brightness(x) when x = 0 -> Brightness (0)
        | Nordic, Off, Brightness(x) -> Brightness (x-1)
        | _, _, _ -> Switch.Off
```

reads easier as

```
let translateCode (state: Switch) (lang: MessageLanguage) (action: Action) =
    match lang, action, state with
        | English, Toggle, _                        -> toggle state
        | English, On,     _                        -> Switch.On
        | Nordic,  Toggle, Brightness(x)            -> Brightness (x+2)
        | Nordic,  On,     Brightness(x)            -> Brightness (x+1)
        | Nordic,  Off,    Brightness(x) when x = 0 -> Brightness (0)
        | Nordic,  Off,    Brightness(x)            -> Brightness (x-1)
        | _,       _,      _                        -> Switch.Off
```

Again, this may or may not be easy to do with your editor (or that
of others who will maintain this code), so it's up to you how to
align these.

## Duplicate code

You may have noticed, the code that solves each of the two problems
is very similar.  Actually, the only places where the two blocks of
code differ, are the name of the array to adjust, and the name of
the language to use for translation.

We can easily extract a function that can be used for both, if we
give it those two changing elements as parameters:

```
let followInstructions (language: MessageLanguage) (lights: Switch[,]) =
    "6.txt"
    |> filereadlines
    |> Seq.map (fun f -> getInstruction f language)
    |> Seq.iter(fun ins ->
        for i in ins.StartRow .. ins.EndRow do
            for j in ins.StartCol .. ins.EndCol do
                lights.[i, j] <- translateCode lights.[i, j] ins.Language ins.Operation)
    lights

let lights = Array2D.create 1000 1000 Switch.Off
lights
|> followInstructions English
|> Seq.cast<Switch>
|> Seq.filter(fun f -> f = Switch.On)
|> Seq.length
|> printfn "The number of lights that are turned on are %i"

let nordiclights = Array2D.create 1000 1000 (Brightness 0)
nordiclights
|> followInstructions Nordic
|> Seq.cast<Switch>
|> Seq.map(fun f -> match f with
                        | Brightness(x) -> x
                        | _             -> 0)
|> Seq.sum
|> printfn "The Santa's real nordic decoded message and the total brightness is %i"
```

## Don't put the `MessageLanguge` in the `Instruction`

The `Instruction` type, and therefor the `getInstruction` function,
both keep track of the `MessageLanguage`.  The instruction does not
contain that information, and only when we translate the instruction
we need that information.  If you remove this field from the
`Instruction` record, the code can be a bit easier to read:

```
type Instruction = {
  Operation: Action
  StartRow: int
  StartCol: int
  EndRow: int
  EndCol: int
}

let getInstruction (line: string) =
    // ...
    match action with
        | Toggle -> {Operation = action; StartRow = elementat 1; StartCol = elementat 2;
                     EndRow = elementat 4 ; EndCol = elementat 5}
        | _      -> {Operation = action; StartRow = elementat 2; StartCol = elementat 3;
                     EndRow = elementat 5 ; EndCol = elementat 6}

let followInstructions (language: MessageLanguage) (lights: Switch[,]) =
    // ...
    |> Seq.map (fun f -> getInstruction f)
    // ...
                    lights.[i, j] <- translateCode lights.[i, j] language ins.Operation)
```

In fact, that line with `Seq.map (fun f -> getInstruction f)` can
now benefit from η-reduction ("eta reduction"), which means that
you don't need to write a placeholder variable name:

```
|> Seq.map getInstruction
```

## Use pattern matching when decoding

The `getInstruction` function can be written more transparent if you
use pattern matching on the list of matches instead of `if`
statements.  This will also remove the need for numerous `elementat`
calls:

```
let getInstruction (line: string) =
    let matches =
        Regex.Matches(line, "[\w\d_]+")
        |> Seq.cast<Match>
        |> Seq.filter (fun f -> f.Success) |> Seq.map(fun f-> f.Value)
        |> Seq.toList

    let operation, [startRow; startCol; _; endRow; endCol] =
        match matches with
            | "toggle" ::lights          -> Toggle, lights
            | "turn"   ::"on"   ::lights -> On, lights
            | "turn"   ::"off"  ::lights -> Off, lights
            | _                          -> failwith "Bad instruction format"

    { Operation = operation; StartRow = int startRow; StartCol = int startCol; EndRow = int endRow; EndCol = int endCol }
```

I also added a `failWith` there, instead of defaulting to `Off` on
invalid input.

## Parameter ordering and partial application

In F#, as in other functional languages, it's customary to order
parameters from "least likely to vary" to "most likely to vary".
This way, you can benefit from partial application, making calls a
bit shorter.  You can do this in `translateCode`, by moving `lang`
to the front.  The partial application will then look as follows:

```
let translateCode (lang: MessageLanguage) (state: Switch) (action: Action) =
    // ...

let followInstructions (language: MessageLanguage) (lights: Switch[,]) =
    let translate = translateCode language
    "6.txt"
    |> filereadlines
    |> Seq.map getInstruction
    |> Seq.iter(fun ins ->
        for i in ins.StartRow .. ins.EndRow do
            for j in ins.StartCol .. ins.EndCol do
                lights.[i, j] <- translate lights.[i, j] ins.Operation)
    lights
```

Now `followInstructions` creates a partial applied function
`translate`, and no longer needs to pass the `language` every time
when calling it.

## Matching on literals

In `translateCode`, you can match on a literal `0` instead of using
a `when` clause.

```
| Nordic,  Off,    Brightness(x) when x = 0 -> Brightness (0)
```

can be written as

```
| Nordic,  Off,    Brightness(0) -> Brightness (0)
```

Or you could combine the two matches on `Nordic, Off`, using the
`max` function:

```
| Nordic,  Off,    Brightness(x) -> Brightness (max (x-1) 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and reviewing it detail. I appreciate it.  Will take this feedback and implement in this as well as in other solutions.

Comment: It was my pleasure!

Comment: You can also find the steps in this review at https://github.com/joranvar/CR-115600. I branched it from your github repository so it could be helpful.